# How to parse POST request in JSON format in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to send a POST request in JSON via curl in ruby on rails. I would like to know how can I parse this request in a controller and save it in database. I've created controller and model for a player.

Below is the curl command -

```
curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" "localhost:3000/app/v2/player" -d '{
"url": "app/v2/players.json",
"para": {
    "player": {
        "player_id": 51275,
        "email": "test@gmail.com",
        "total_won": "1890000.00",
        "pr_costs": "29.00",
        "payment_method": "VISA",
        "games": [
            {
                "name": "AvsB",
                "matches": 1,
                "value": 1100,
                "category": "Cricket",
                "subcategory": "Test",
                "tags": [
                    "Aus",
                    "Melbourne"
                ],
                "game_id": 12                   
            },
            {
                "name": "CvsD",
                "matches": 1,
                "value": 790,
                "category": "Cricket",
                "subcategory": "T20",
                "tags": [
                    "T20",
                    "20over",
                    "worldcup"
                ],
                "game_id": 7
            }
        ]
    }
}
}'
```

Below is my player controller-

```
module App
module V2
    class PlayersController < ApplicationController

  def create

    @player = Player.new(params[[:para][:player][:player_id]].first)
    if @player.save
        render json: @player, status: 201, location: @player

    else
        render json: @player.errors, status: 422
    end
  end


private  

def player_params
  #params.require(:player).permit(:url, :player_id, :email, :total_won, :pr_costs, :payment_method)
  params.fetch(:url,:para, {}).permit(:player_id, :email, :total_won, :pr_costs, :payment_method)

end
    end
end
end
```

Below is my player model -

```
class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :games, dependent: :destroy
validates :player_id, presence: true
attr_accessor :url,:para


end
```

Currently I'm getting below error while initiating the curl command -

```
 TypeError (no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer):
 app/controllers/app/v2/players_controller.rb:21:in `[]'
 app/controllers/app/v2/players_controller.rb:21:in `create'
```

Any pointers on how I can read JSON data and create records for players in create function and related games would be appreciated. I've not created the model for games but it'll be similar in structure to JSON data. Also one player has many games and a game will belong to a Player.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: why do you have an extra `[]` in the `params`
try `params[:para][:player]`

Answer (score 0):

This is badly structured.

```
[[:para][:player][:player_id]]
```

It basically means (in part) there's an array that contains the player symbole

```
[:player]
```

and you want to get the ':player_id(th)' entry of that array or string... which is where you're getting the error ("How do I convert a symbol into an integer for the array?")

```
[:player][:player_id]
```

you probably want...

```
params[:para][:player][:player_id]
```

There's no 'first' because there's no array in the `:player_id` entry.

Comment: if I use `@player = Player.new(params[:para][:player][:player_id])` , I get an error that says `ArgumentError (When assigning attributes, you must pass a hash as an argument.):
  app/controllers/app/v2/players_controller.rb:21:in `create' ` Could you please advise what I am doing wrong here ?

Comment: drop `[:player_id]` as that's just one element.  If you drop it, you're now passing a hash.  You'll probably get another error because you're passing additional parameters that aren't useful but we'll have made progress

Comment: Or do a comprehensive `player_params` method (reinstate `require`) and then reference `player_params` instead of the params directly.

Comment: Thank you, but how do I write my player_params method to permit parameters. The one that I've written clearly doesn't represent my json structure. `params.require(:player).permit(:url, :player_id, :email, :total_won, :pr_costs, :payment_method)`, and it doesn't include games as well. Any pointers will be helpful!

Comment: Is 'games' an ActiveRecord table?  There's a many-to-one between `games` and `players`?

Answer (score 0):

As it always happens, I figured it out myself. Below is what I used for player_params function. There could be other ways as well, but this certainly worked for me.

```
params.require(:player).permit(:url,:para =>[:player =>[:player_id, :email, :total_won, :pr_costs, :payment_method,:games =>[:name, :matches, :value, :category, :subcategory, :game_id ]]])
```

@SteveTurczyn thanks for pointing me in the right direction